# it displays wrong information after drop down option selected

Tags: php, html, mysqli

In code below I have a query which retrives all of the modules from db and then list them as options in a drop down menu. Now what is suppose to happen is that user selects a module from the drop down menu and submit. After submit it will display underneath the module the user has selectd.

The problem is that no matter which module the user has chosen from the drop down menu, it always states that the user has selected the `Advanced Web programming` module. My question is why is it always stating this and not instead displaying the correct module chosen?

Below is the VIEW SOURCE code:

```
<form action="" method="post">Module:
  <select name="module" id="modulesDrop">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option selected='selected' value='CHI2513_Systems Strategy_1'>CHI2513 - Systems Strategy</option>
    <option value='CHI2565_Ecommerce, Business and Technology_3'>CHI2565 - Ecommerce, Business and Technology</option>
    <option value='CHT2220_Interactive Systems_4'>CHT2220 - Interactive Systems</option>
    <option value='CHT2520_Advanced Web Programming_5'>CHT2520 - Advanced Web Programming</option>
  </select>
  <input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" />
</form>
<form action="" method="post">
  <p> <strong>Selected Module:</strong>CHT2520 - Advanced Web Programming
    <input type='text' value='CHI2513_Systems Strategy_1' />
  </p>
  Asessments: <span class='red'>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</span>
```

Below is the written code:

```
$moduleactive = 1;
            $sql = "SELECT ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleActive = ? ORDER BY ModuleNo"; 

            $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
            $sqlstmt->bind_param("i", $moduleactive);
            $sqlstmt->execute(); 
            $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbModuleId,$dbModuleNo,$dbModuleName);
            $sqlstmt->store_result();
            $sqlnum = $sqlstmt->num_rows();
            ?>
            Module: 
            <select name="module" id="modulesDrop">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <?php
                while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
                    $ov = $dbModuleNo . "_" . $dbModuleName . "_" . $dbModuleId; 
                    if($ov == $_POST["module"]) 
                        echo "<option selected='selected' value='$ov'>$dbModuleNo - $dbModuleName</option>" . PHP_EOL; 
                    else 
                        echo "<option value='$ov'>$dbModuleNo - $dbModuleName</option>" . PHP_EOL;
                 } 
                ?>
            </select>
            <input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" />
        </form>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])) 
{


if($_POST["module"] != "") { ?>
        <form action="" method="post"> 
            <p>
            <strong>Selected Module:</strong><?php echo $dbModuleNo .' - '. $dbModuleName;?> <input type='text' value='<?php echo $_POST["module"];?>'>
            </p>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Just asking - what `WHERE ModuleActive = ?` statement means?

Comment: @Kamo ? is a parameter. The parameter is stored here: `$sqlstmt->bind_param("i", $moduleactive);
` and `$moduleactive = 1;`. So the WHERE statement is `WHERE ModuleActive = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little rusty on my PHP, but I believe it is because the module `Advanced Web Programming` is last in the list. Your variables `$dbModuleNo` and `$dbModuleName` are updated every time you run through the while loop fetching rows from the DB, so by the time you want to display the selected module, these variables contain the most recently fetched data, not the selected data as you want.

Try something like this (I've added a few lines to your existing code):

```
<?php
$selectedText = "None";
while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
    $ov = $dbModuleNo . "_" . $dbModuleName . "_" . $dbModuleId; 
    if($ov == $_POST["module"]) 
        echo "<option selected='selected' value='$ov'>$dbModuleNo - $dbModuleName</option>" . PHP_EOL;
        $selectedText = $dbModuleNo .' - '. $dbModuleName;
    else 
        echo "<option value='$ov'>$dbModuleNo - $dbModuleName</option>" . PHP_EOL;
} 
?>
```

and then later...

```
<strong>Selected Module:</strong><?php echo $selectedText;?>
```